# How to use WhatsApp Api to send messages from Businesses to Customers

Tags: android, ios, react-native, facebook, whatsapp

I am developing a B2C application for local business. I will be developing separate apps for businesses and customers but to cater to the customers who do not have the app yet, I wish to provide Businesses with the functionality that they can send invoices to their customer's WhatsApp through my Business App from their WhatsApp Number.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use whatsapp business API - https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api/?lang=fb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what format your invoice is, if it is plain text or image, for **Android** you can just use `Intent` to share it to WhatsApp

---

**1. Share Text**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String packageName = "com.tencent.mm";          //you can try "com.whatsapp" for WhatsApp or "com.facebook.orca" for Messenger

    if (isAppInstalled(packageName)) {              //if app found
        String text = "I love you";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        intent.setPackage(packageName);

        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "WeChat is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    boolean installed = true;

    try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0); //if package not found, exception will be thrown
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }

    return installed;
}
```

---

**2. Share Image**

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);     //uri from loading onto the page
        intent.setPackage(packageName);             //such as "com.tencent.mm"

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, invoice will be in plain text and a link to play store and app store